# Как запустить Firefox через proxy, selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, proxy, firefox

Как запустить firefox через прокси?

Comment: StackOverflow для вопросов и ответов (а не для гайдов или туториалов). Вам стоит переформулировать вопрос в вопрос и вынести ответ в ответ.

Comment: хорошо, переделаю

Comment: И учтите, вопрос должен быть достаточно конкретным )

Answer (score 0):

Приветсвую! Недавно разбирался как же запустить Firefox через прокси и через несколько часов нашёл ответ. Для начала давайте создадим `Options`

```
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
'''Зададим директорию нашего браузера'''
options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
```

Возможно вы спросите почему ты не используешь `webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX` потому что у меня с ним не работает, скорее всего это связанно с совершенствованием браузеров и самого selenium.
Дальше мы зададим параметры

```
options.set_capability('marionette', True)
    options.capabilities['proxy'] = {
        "httpProxy": proxy,
        "sslProxy": proxy,
        "proxyType": "MANUAL"
        }
```

Возможно у вас возникнет вопрос: а где `ftpProxy`? А я отвечу: Он устарел, по крайней мере такую ошибку выводил сам selenium.
Дальше укажем директорию `geckodriver`:

```
s = Service(r'C:\Users\Костьян\Desktop\Projects\VK REPOST\Proxy_test\geckodriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=s, options=options)
```

У вас опять же может возникнуть вопрос: а где у тебя `executable_path`? Он тоже частично устарел и при его использовании будет предупреждение, но его можно использовать.
в итоге у нас получается код:

```
    options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
    options.set_capability('marionette', True)
    options.capabilities['proxy'] = {
        "httpProxy": proxy,
        "sslProxy": proxy,
        "proxyType": "MANUAL"
        }    
    s = Service(r'C:\Users\Костьян\Desktop\Projects\VK REPOST\Proxy_test\geckodriver.exe')
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=s, options=options)
```

Если я что то сказал неправильно или сделал где то ошибку не стесняйтесь писать, давайте вместе поможем разобраться начинающим пользователям selenium =)